# Detach CMake references from the generated solution/project files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I have a CMake project which generates a Visual Studio solution and its associated project files.  I've noticed that there are a lot of "CustomBuild" rules generated in the projects which seem to re-run CMake if for some reason the projects are not up-to-date:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuild Include="foo\CMakeLists.txt">
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Building Custom Rule S:/foo/CMakeLists.txt</Message>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">setlocal
"C:\...\cmake.exe" -HS:/foo -BS:/foo/msvc-10.0 --check-stamp-file S:\foo\msvc-10.0\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp
      ...
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is there a way to tell CMake to disable generating these custom build rules?  My goal is to have CMake generate solution/project files without still being attached to CMake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that can't be done.

Moreover, those rules are not only for re-generating project files if they're not up-to-date anymore. For instance, there's also the CMake command mode that provides portability for copying files, directories, md5 sums and many other nice things.

The [bakefile](http://www.bakefile.org/index.html) project tried to do that (generating independent project files), but it seems it's pretty much dead now.